# Set current user to created django model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-import-export

I've been looking for a solution to this, for a couple of days now, and I can't make it work.

The scenario is this:

I'm trying to import data (e.g. of type CountryCondition) by using django import-export, and before that, I want to validate them. If some rows contain invalid data, I want to create a Message object with the error and save it. The Message model has a Foreign Key to User, so when a user logs in, he can see all messages related to him.

Here is my code

*The **Message** model:*

```
class Message(models.Model):
    """ Message. """

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    msg_text = models.CharField(max_length=512, verbose_name=_('Message'))
```

*The **CountryConditions** ModelResource:*

```
class CountryConditionsResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def skip_row(self, instance, original):
        ...
        message = Message(msg_text='a message')
        with transaction.atomic():
            message.save()
```

What I would like is for the message to be saved for the currently logged user.

Thank you very much in advance

**Edit 1:** *The **CountryConditions** model* (as per @Rahul Gupta request)

```
class CountryConditions(models.Model):

    country = models.OneToOneField(Country, verbose_name=_('country_name'))
    iec_current = models.DecimalField( max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, verbose_name=_('iec_current'))
    iec_current_one = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, verbose_name=_('iec_current_one'))
    iec_final = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, default=0.00, verbose_name=_('iec_final'))

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Conditions for %s' % self.country.name

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        self.calculate_iec_final()
        super(CountryConditions, self).save()

    def calculate_iec_final(self):
        ...

    class Meta:
        ...
```

Comment: the user you want is, assuming you have a request, `request.user`, plus some checking to deal with anon.

Comment: Can you add the code for `CountryConditions` model also.

Comment: @RahulGupta, thank you for your response. I have editing my question and included the CountryConditions model.

Comment: How is `CountryConditions` model related to a `User`? If we have an instance of `CountryConditions`, how would we know it is for which user.

Comment: @RahulGupta, it is not related. Only Message domain is associated with a User. So, at the time I'm validating CountryConditions, I want to create Message objects and set the current user to them.